# UserControl not getting repainted if placed in panel

Tags: c#, user-controls, repaint

I've got two user controls. First one, called "Indicator" is a simple Control that paints a square using OnPaint(...); No place for an error in first UserControl.

```
public partial class Indicator : UserControl
{
    public Indicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0,0,this.Width,this.Height);
    }
}
```

The second one is a test control and consists of a panel, which contains a picture box and the first user control brought to front.

```
public partial class testIndicator: UserControl
{
    private static Bitmap bmp;
    public Indicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadImage();
        pictureBox.Image = bmp;
        indicator.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

When I launch the test control in a dialog (From a form to make sure the program remains running) it displays fine the first time. However if the dialog is closed and opened again (while the program is still running) the OnPaint Method on Indicator doesn't get fired.

It works fine if indicator is placed without a panel onto UserControl.

And just to be clear, I've tried running Invalidate() and Invalidate()+Update() manually while testing, no changes.

Could anyone explain this behavior or possibly know a similar container that doesn't have such issue?

Edit: The mistake was so stupid that i failed to even consider it as a possibility;
The PictureBox uses a static Image, and i had code to only initialize the image once. The problem is it had a "Size largeScaleSize" object that is not static and gets initialized together with images. Since images already exist on 2nd run largeScaleSize does not get initiaized and is basically {0,0}. Scaling method has this line:

```
float xRatio = (float)this.tankPanel.Width / (float)largeScaleSize.Width;
//same as "xRatio = this.tankPanel.Width  / 0" which is infinity
```

I only wonder why I never got a Division By Zero exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small project from your description. You can download it [here](http://1drv.ms/1npAQtA). 
Panel was anchored to every edge in the second user control. Picture box and Indicator control were docked top and bottom inside the panel. A form containing the composite user control is run modally/modelessly. Could not reproduce faulty behavior.

Comment: Your answer is not exactly what I was looking for. But it DOES answer the the actual question. Also it pointed me the right way, so thanks a lot!